# Gnu parallel for copying large amount of data(around 40 GB)

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu

My requirement is simple but unable to find a way to do it effectively.

I have a directory named Code which contains around 14lac files and is around 40 GB. All i want to do is to create a copy of this Code folder at same directory level. Means Code and Code_Copy are in same folder.

If i use **find . | parallel cp -rpf {} ../Code_Copy** in Code folder, i get the correct directory structure plus all the files present in Code folder recursively also directly copied to Code_Copy.

If i use **tree | parallel cp -rpf {} ../Code_Copy**, the directory structure is created properly but the command keeps on running for a long time even after that giving error on "cannot stat file :" etc for lines of output of tree command.

Pls help in providing a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copying data in parallel makes little sense unless you're copying to or from multiple destinations. Try `rsync`.

Comment: @larsmans While that used to be universally true, these days it depends a lot on your disk system: I have worked on disk systems where running 10 jobs in parallel gave a speed up of 600%. So the best advice is to measure how many parallel jobs give the optimal performance.

Comment: @OleTange: ok, I guess for big SSDs it might work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tree will fail because it does not give paths but draws the paths using ascii art. This is not useful input for parallel.

The simplest solution is:

```
cp -a Code Code_Copy
```

but that may be slow. Running rsync in parallel may be the fastest solution depending on your disk system:

```
find . -type f | parallel 'mkdir -p ../Copy/{//}; rsync -a {} ../Copy/{}'
# To get permissions and special files fixed
rsync -a ./ ../Copy/
```

To get the most out of GNU Parallel consider walking through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: That pretty much worked. But it still takes a long time for the copying to be done, similar to simple copy command.  I assumed that it copies different files parallely to the destination location. Pls correct me if i am wrong. And how to run multiple instances.. like parallel -j10 'mkdir -p ../Copy/{//}; rsync -a {} ../Copy/{}' should run 10 instances of this and copying should be done in a couple of minutes. Pls sugggest

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but you need to do it in two steps. Build the directory tree first, then copy in the files. From the parent directory of **Code**:

```
NUM_JOBS=4
find Code -type d -print0 | parallel -j$NUM_JOBS -0 "mkdir -p Code_Copy/{}"
find Code ! -type d -print0 | parallel -j$NUM_JOBS -0 "cp -P {} Code_Copy/{}"
```

The **-P** option preserves softlinks within the tree copied.